# Copying a local Database and mailing it.

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-sdcard

I have made an application which is about pets, at first I had kept the database local to the phone, however as new features arrive I want to make it a network based application with remote database. However I have around 500 downloads on the play store and I dont want my previous users to lose data. I came up with an idea of rolling out an update in which I copy all the databases to the SD card and then mail them back to me and update them in the remote database. I wonder if there is a better way to go around this. Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to write a webservice to which you can send the database row by row. The webservice will then update your Server database(s).

This not only prevents duplication of your database between internal and external memory, but it also allows automation and more flexibility in the update process. You can also pause the transfer, and pick up from whichever row was last sent easily.

Comment: How do I achieve that? Where do I start? Can you provide me a heading?